# TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, react-hooks

I'm creating a list of icons like [this website](https://icons.expo.fyi/). I'm trying to create a dynamic search bar that searches icons from the list of data. The list of icons is displaying; however, when I'm tapping on the search bar, I have the following error: **TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function**.
Thanks for your help!

```js
//Parent
import iconData from "./icon_data.json";
import ResultContainer from "./ResultContainer";

const fetchIconData = () => Promise.resolve(() => iconData);

export type ModalProps = {
    setModalVisible: (value: any) => void;
    setProp: (value: any) => void;
    modalVisible: boolean | undefined;
};

export const ModalIcons = ({setModalVisible, modalVisible, setProp,}: Partial<ModalProps>) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchIconData().then((jsonData) => setData(jsonData));
  }, []);

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const results = !searchTerm
    ? data
    : data.filter(name =>
        name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
  );


  return (
      <Modal
          isOpen={modalVisible?modalVisible:false}
          onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible && setModalVisible(false)
        }}
      > 
      <View >
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
        <ResultContainer data={results} setProp={setProp} />
      </View>
      </Modal>
  );
};
```

```js
//Child
import ResultRow from "./ResultRow";

type ResultContainerProps = {
  data: [],
  setProp: (value: any) => void;
}

const ResultContainer = ({
  data,
  setProp,
}:Partial <ResultContainerProps>) => {

  return (
    <>
      {data.map(({ family, names }) => {
        return <ResultRow title={family} icons={names} family={family} setProp={setProp} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ResultContainer;
```

```js
//icon_data.json
[
    {
      "family": "AntDesign",
      "names": ["stepforward", "stepbackward", "forward", "banckward"]
    },
    {
      "family": "Entypo",
      "names": ["500px", "500px-with-circle", "add-to-list", "add-user"]
    }
]
```

Comment: `name` in `name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())` is not a string.

Comment: Can you add a https://CodeSandbox.io for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `state` or `props` dynamically, it might be possible that the value is not loaded. So use this way:

```
name && name.toLowerCase && name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
```

I feel the main issue looks like it's a data issue? What if you get undefined?